# UI Matrix for Mobile Devices

Tags: mobile

Does anyone have or seen a nice Matrix or Dashboard listing the capabilities between viewing a mobile website on a smart phone and on a non-smart phone?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure this is a direct answer, but have you read this: http://www.passani.it/gap/

specifically section 1.3?

Comment: Seems unrelated to UI, as it mostly talks about what to pay attention to when implementing (outdated) XHTML-MP. Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 2):

The new jQuery Mobile site has a pretty detailed chart for mobile graded browser support:

[Mobile Graded Browser Support](http://jquerymobile.com/gbs/)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure that all the capabilities can be summed up in a single chart. [Programming the Mobile Web](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0596807783) is an excellent resource for this though as the author dedicates multiple chapters of his book to that very question.

Answer (score 1):

This might help you:
http://www.quirksmode.org/webkit.html

Your question is a little bit vague.
What are you looking for specifically?